# Limiting tabu caption width

Tags: tables, captions, tabu, threeparttable

I am attempting to constrain the width of my table captions to be no wider than the table itself.  When using `tabular` I typically accomplish this with `threeparttable` as

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
 \begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Table caption, which can be long, goes here.}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
     Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
 \end{table}
```

however, if I switch from `tabular` to `tabu` this no longer works with LaTeX giving an error that "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tabu}".  How can I either resolve this incompatibility or obtain a similar result without `threeparttable` (under the assumption that I have no prior knowledge of the width of the table).

Comment: you had to have very cogent arguments for switching from `tabular` to `tabu`. `tabu` beside some attractive features which it has is unfortunately not maintained and buggy.